# Understanding struct itimerval field tv_usec

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, setitimer

Hi I'm studying this code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


volatile sig_atomic_t print_flag = true;
static int count = 0;

void timer_handler (int signum)
{

 printf ("timer expired %d times\n", ++count);
 if(count>20) {
    print_flag = false;
 } 
}

int main ()
{
 struct sigaction sa;
 struct itimerval timer;

 /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
 memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
 sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
 sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

 /* Configure the timer to expire after 250 msec... */
 timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
 timer.it_value.tv_usec = 250000;
 /* ... and every 250 msec after that. */
 timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 250000;
 /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is
   executing. */
 setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

 /* Do busy work. */
 while (print_flag) {
    sleep(1);
 }

printf("job done bye bye\n");
    exit(0);

}
```

With this settings everything goes fine and i get this output

```
...
timer expired 17 times
timer expired 18 times
timer expired 19 times
timer expired 20 times
timer expired 21 times
job done bye bye
```

If i try to alter the code commenting `timer.it_interval.tv_usec` and      `timer.it_interval.tv_usec`and setting both  `timer.it_value.tv_sec` and `timer.it_value.tv_sec` equal to, for instance, 3 it doesn't do his job.

However if I maintain an explicit declaration of `tv_usec` like this it works:

```
 timer.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
 timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
 timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 3;
 timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
```

Why I'm bonded on the explicit declaration of `tv_usec` for both fields?

Comment: It probably isn't the cause of your trouble, but see [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/) for information on which functions you're allowed to call in a signal handler.  Note that `printf()` is not one of those functions, officially (and neither is `strlen()` – and while I can explain `printf()`, I find `strlen()` much harder to explain).

Comment: thanks man i totally forgot about that!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as you don't initialize `*.tv_usec` fields, theirs values are **undefined**. If it'd contain a value greater that `999999` or less than `0`, the `setitimer ()`  will just fail with `EINVAL` as described on the man page.

You ought to initialize all the data yourself. If you are willing to save a line of code, you may `memset` the `timer` struct to `0` the same way you have done it for `sa`.